# How do I use DoCmd.TransferText and provide progress update to user?

Tags: ms-access

I am using DoCmd.TransferText to batch import multiple text files into a database at recurring periods.  The program runs successfully, but in appearance, the user receives no feedback that it is running.

I have attempted using SysCmd to create both a meter and status update, but these appear to quickly be overwritten when the TransferText method begins.

How can I provide some kind of indication to the user that the process is running, and how far along it is.

Currently, I am using the variables `count` and `total` to indicate the current progress, and the total number of files, respectively.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: How are you launching the import process? Could you run it from a form and add the progress meter to the form?

Comment: Do you want to display progress like *"1 of 12 files transferred"*, or something else?

Comment: @HansUp, that's exactly what I am trying to do.  Matt, currently I am launching it from VBA editor.  Unsure as to where the controls will reside; a form is possible.

Comment: Present a form with a text box.  In a `For` loop where you do `DoCmd.TransferText`, write an updated message to the text box: count of total.

Comment: That should suffice.  However, if I want to get fancy and add an animated Windows progress bar, would this possible with a COM object of some sort?